# We can paint in a piece of paper but why can't we paint in the air?

Tags: physics

People might say that is is because air has no source to absorb the paint but even air has molecules so then, why is it that we can't paint in the air?

Comment: Because in order to paint you would need to use paint and air is not a good medium to deposit said paint!

Comment: You absolutely can. see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skywriting . You can also have a dye molecule in a matrix of nitrogen molecules which technically would also be "painting in the air".

Comment: We *can* paint in the air. The problem is that air is a fluid, and molecules in a fluid move around *a lot*, thus dispersing the pigment and effacing the image.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As the name might suggest, here we like worldbuilding questions. Your looks hardly as such. Can you rework it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With science and tech we have today, and probably in the future as well, it can't be done (In a way that resembles other types of painting, like the example you give in your question).
The main reason is that air is gas, and to paint it, you would need gas as well. The way gas behaves is expanding to fill what ever container it is in. (Not exactly expand, a more accurate description would be to say that gas particles tend to move apart from one another).
This causes a problem, because if We were to release a "gas-paint" it would quickly spread away.
If we would take a closed space (e.g. a glass box) and fill it with said "gas-paint" it won't spread, but would be either heavier or lighter then the air in the box, causing it to either collect on the bottom or top (respectively) of the box.

Comment: Are you suggesting that "gas particles" do not move anymore (except for up and down) if you put them into a "closed glass box"?

Comment: Of course not. They still move, but within confined borders. What I tried to express is that even if you try work-arounds, the concept still won't work. The box part was a non-general way of saying "even if you overcome gas-paint dispersing".

Comment: When you say gas-paint collects at either the top or bottom of the closed glass box doesn't that mean that the bottom or the top of the box would be colored?https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/37861/raditz-35

Comment: @AryaShrestha This would be an overcomplicated approach. There wouldn't be a clear cut line either, they would still mix quite heavily. You might experience a small color density gradient. Just use a colored gas in a box (of a shape you like) then. Get enough of such glass boxes in various shapes filled with various colored gases and you can create a great painting.

Comment: Well, since the color we are using is also gas, if it's just concentrated in one place, I would say it's not coloring. It could be compared to a large amount of color on a piece of paper. Aside from the lower layer of paint that gets absorbed, the rest of the paint isn't really coloring the page. In any case, this is becoming more a discussion of philosophy and phrasing, not WB or even physics.

Comment: @AryaShrestha To tag another user in your comment, just type `@` followed by their name, as I did. It even autocompletes for you.

Comment: Why not simply say that it's because gas molecules are too far apart to support paint molecules?